# How to display annotation MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in MVC 4 and I'm struggling to displaying the error message for the required field. please help

this is in my model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required Field")]
public string Username { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

this is in my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser","User", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(l => l.Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Username)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Username);
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(l => l.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Password)
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify if you want the validation message to always appear or just when the form is submitted, and please post the relevant rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are taking about client validation because it looks like your server validation should work.

Are you loading the correct scripts for client validation?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

Also make sure these settings are in your web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Please whether you have included the necessary javascript files for unobtrusive validation in the right order and that will make the validation happen successfully at the client-side.

```
jquery.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Regarding the server side validation you have to save the model to the database by explicitly checking `ModelState.IsValid`.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to you model annotations you need to reference jquery validation library to your page for client side validation.

```
jquery.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```